# QUERY with AND criteria not returning expected results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a `QUERY` that seems to be treating `AND` more like `OR`.  In other words, when the value of `Col11=TRUE` and the value of `Col12=7`, the results are displayed as though `Col12=8`.  Am I missing something?  I've tried adding quotes around the variables, parentheses around the two criteria.  Adding spacing around the `=`.  What else is there?

`Col11` is only `TRUE` or `FALSE` values and `Col12` is only numeric values from 1-8.

```
=QUERY({$A$3:$AJ},"SELECT Col3,Col10 where Col11=TRUE and Col12=8",0)
```

Here's a [link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mZn5W7JN8o6OPNkGZ0DTetP-K5i1auIyF9hcuKw6HC8/edit#gid=940565536&range=AK2).  It's buried in a larger formula in AK2

AK6 is a good example.  It shows `U U`.  It should only show `U`.  It is treat X6 as though it's value is 8 when it is actually 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I worked out what is happening.
You are getting two 'U's because I think your inner array is returning multiple rows for `Col3='R2-D2'`, one row where `Col23=TRUE` and `Col24=8`, and then another row where `Col27=TRUE` and `Col28=8`.

I'm not positive, but I think the values in AK don't relate specifically to the values in that specific row, but instead relate to an array queried across all of your data rows.  So as the outer ArrayFormula works down the column, the inner array (with multiple VLOOKUP/ArrayFormula/Queries) is still a large subset of the whole data range.  That's assuming I've understood your complex formula correctly - my apologies if I've misunderstood something.

I've added a Heroes-TEST sheet to your sheet.  It only has ten rows, all of the R2-D2 data from your Heroes tab.  The columns are collapsed for visibility.  See what happens when you highlight all the row data below Row3 and press delete - and then UNDO.  The two 'U's in column AK become one, because there is only one row of data to query through now.
Your original formula is in AK2.

Let me know if this has helped.

Comment: I believe you’re right. I broke the formula down to expand the first results and, as you said, the results did not correspond to the rows I was expecting. I ultimately switched to a series of IF statements for now.

Comment: Yes, it was a bit of a struggle to work through, and I don't always really understand how compound ArrayFormulas work.  I'm still not sure why the test formula in my AL3 didn't work, trying to constrain the array to one row.  Pretty impressive sheet you've made there!